# bash: export: `--wait': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, quoting, variable-substitution

When I run [git-sh](https://github.com/rtomayko/git-sh) from my terminal it works fine. But I get the following warning.

```
bash: export: `--wait': not a valid identifier
```

What is this and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: I'd look for lines containing `--wait` in ~/.gitshrc because you've probably have an error in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in that script is a line like

```
export VAR=$SOMETHING
```

and the value of the variable `SOMETHING` contains a space followed by `--wait`, e.g. `$SOMETHING` may be `foo --wait` or `foo --wait=42`. The bash builtin `export` thus receives two arguments, `VAR=foo` (a perfectly valid assignment) and `--wait`, which is not a valid variable name.

The fix is to use double quotes. Always use double quotes around variable substitutions. Either of these will do:

```
export VAR="$SOMETHING"
export "VAR=$SOMETHING"
```

To find which line is affected, run `bash -x ./git-sh` instead of `./git-sh`, or `set -x; . git-sh; set +x` instead of `. git-sh`. The shell will print a trace of the lines it executes; look for the error in the trace.